# How to add runtime library in Ada multi 7.2.4

Tags: ada

I am trying t execute ada multi program using batch file but I am getting this errors:

_d_dtof
_d_dmul

For the below line:
long float := long float (int) * long float;

Comment: long float := long float(int) * long float; This line only specifies data types without specifying variables. Multiplication and assignment only work on variables or initialization of constants, not on data types.

Answer (score 0):

I think he mean to say for variables only for example

long float : a, b, c;
integer : x;
NOW...

a := b(x) * c;

even I got the same errors for that line but the difference is when using IDE (Ada multi 7.2.4 tool) I did not got any errors, but same code when I used using command promt I got errors. Which means a run time library is unable to link those errors.

I got the below errors...
_d_dtof
_d_add
_d_div
_d_ftod
_d_sub
_d_itod
_d_utod
_d_dtou

and the code is in Ada language.